# Configure ShingleFilterFactory to ignore tokens with same start and end

Tags: solr, lucene

I was using Shingle Fitler with Suggester to implement an autosuggest dropdown. The field I'm using with shingle filter has a worddelimiter with preserveoriginal=1 to tokenize "women's" as "women's" and "womens."

Because of this, when shingle filter is generating word ngrams, apart from the expected tokens, there's also a "women's womens" tokens. I wanted to know if there's any way to configure ShingleFilter so that it ignores tokens with same start and end values.

Answer (score 0):

I would think that just eliminating that token isn't good enough.  Say your working with the phrase `"red women's shoes"`, and you end up with:

```
"red women's" "women's womens" "womens shoes"
```

Just eliminating the middle token leaves you with:

```
"red women's" "womens shoes"
```

In which case, the SynonymFilter is just adding inconsistency, rather than flexibility.

For the same reasons that preserving originals on a `SynonymFilter` gets in the way of `PhraseQueries` (See the note near the top of the [SynonymFilter documentation](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_2_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/synonym/SynonymFilter.html)), I don't see a good way to make it get along with a `ShingleFilter`.  Would it be possible to not set it to preserve original tokens, and apply the SynonymFilter at both index and query time?

Comment: I thought Shingle filter would consider token positions and ngram according to that. For instance here it according to positions, it should have generated tokens as: "red women's", "red womens", "women's shoes", "womens shoes". But just checked it myself, and it doesn't. So on what basis does it consider next and previous tokens?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilter.

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory

Best